# How to query associated models in Node/Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm building an app in express and I'm using postgres and sequelize for ORM. I have two models, `User` and `Post`.

In my `user.js` and `post.js` files I have:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ""
    },

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('posts', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ""
    },
```

I imported those two models and I made the following associations:

```
User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });

Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

I am trying to render all the posts done by a user, but I'm probably missing something.

In my routes I can get the correct user but I don't know how to proceed.

```
router.route('/:id').get(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  console.log(user);
  res.send(user);
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[findById](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findById)** does not support the associated model ,

```
User.findById(req.params.id);
```

You can change `findById` to `findOne` and include model like this ,

```
User.findOne({
    where : { id : req.params.id },
    include : {
        model : Post
    }
});
```